# Does a parent have any heightened duty of care to a grown child?

Tags: united-states, civil-law

In the US, does a parent have any heightened duty of care to a grown child than that of an adult stranger to another adult?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you rephrase it in proper English? What does "grown child" mean to you?

Comment: Looks like there is a typo or mistaken choice of word. I can't make sense of what is being asked either.

Comment: I think it asks whether an adult (18+) parent has a higher duty of care to his/her adult child than does Adult A to unrelated Adult B.

Comment: A.fm. that's exactly right. I hope my edit helps.   Sorry for the sloppy original typing

Comment: Ah . . . that make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes.

Financial aid programs presume a parental contribution and will deny any aid to students whose parents don't cooperate in the process unless they qualify as "independent" (e.g. if they are married).

A parent generally has an obligation to support an adult child who suffers from a disability that prevents them from functioning.

But, generally speaking, parents have few legal obligations to their adult children.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ohwilleke. Do you happen to have any references available for the obligation for support in case of disability?

Comment: The reverse legal obligation is often present https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filial_responsibility_laws